# Writing new key to configuration file with Viper

Tags: go, viper-go

First easy project with Go here.

Based on user input, I need to add new keys to my existing configuration file.
I manage to read it correctly with Viper and use it throughout the application, but `WriteConfig` doesn't seem to work.

Here's a snippet:

```
        oldConfig := viper.AllSettings()
        fmt.Printf("All settings #1 %+v\n\n", oldConfig)

        viper.Set("setting1", chosenSetting1)
        viper.Set("setting2", chosenSetting2)

        newConfig := viper.AllSettings()
        fmt.Printf("All settings #2 %+v\n\n", newConfig)

        err := viper.WriteConfig()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
```

`newConfig` includes new settings as expected, but `WriteConfig` doesn't apply changes to the config file.

I've read in Viper repo that writing functions are quite controversial and a bit buggy in terms of treating existing or non-existing files, but I expect them to work in simple cases like this.

I also tried other functions (i.e. `SafeWriteConfig`) with no success.

I'm using Go 1.16.2 and Viper 1.7.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To test : try `WriteConfigAs(filename)` ; you will be able to name the file to write to.

Comment: `viper.ConfigFileUsed()` should return the path used by default. If there is no error in `WriteConfig`, it's probably that the changes are not written to the file you expect.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out I was actually trying to write to a different file. There are several problems with Viper, in particular, this bug needs a work-around in how you read and write the config file: https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/1017

Comment: If you want to answer officially, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `WriteConfigAs(filename)` ; you will be able to name the file to write to.

If there is no error in WriteConfig, it's probably that the changes are not written to the file you expect.

`viper.ConfigFileUsed()` should return the path used by default.

Comment: Thanks. Final solution was to read the file with full path and extension: `viper.SetConfigFile(path.Join(home, ".myconfig.json"))`.

Comment: And I specified the full path and extension even in writing: `viper.WriteConfigAs(viper.ConfigFileUsed())`

Answer (score 2):

```
viper.WriteConfig() // writes current config to predefined path set by 'viper.AddConfigPath()' and 'viper.SetConfigName'
```

you first need to specify the path to the config file

or try this method bellow

```
viper.SafeWriteConfigAs("/path/to/my/.config") // will error since it has already been written
```

Comment: Thanks. Turned out I was actually trying to write to a different file. There are several problems with Viper, in particular, this bug needs a work-around in how you read and write the config file: https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/1017